# How to batch copy & rename files?

Tags: windows, batch, copy-paste

I'm using windows server 2012 R2. I have a folder with a bunch of files and I want to copy for every file in that folder 20 times into another folder but the newly copied file has to be renamed using single alphabetical orders. For example a file called "orange.html" gets copied 20 times and moved to another folder. The new folder would contain 20 new copied files with file names such as a.html, b.html, c.html etc.

This is the code but all it does increment by numbers but I want to increment by the alphabet

```
@echo off

for /L %%i IN (1,1,100) do call :docopy %%i
goto end

:docopy
set FN=00%1
set FN=%FN:~-3%

copy source-file.html poll%FN%.html

:end
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I've edited my question. Is this helpful now?

Comment: That is much better ;)

Comment: You cannot copy both file1.html, file2.html, etc  20 times to the same names a.html, b.html, c.html ... in the same folder. You need to clarify your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### All it does increment by numbers but I want to increment by the alphabet

The following batch file (test.cmd) should get you started:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "chars=abcedefhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
for /l %%i in (0,1,25) do (
  echo copy source-file.html folder\poll!chars:~%%i,1!.html
  )
endlocal
```

Notes:

- This is a partial answer because your requirements are not clear.
- Use the above batch file as a starting point
- It shows how to construct the file names using incremental letters of the alphabet.

Example output:

```
copy source-file.html folder\polla.html
copy source-file.html folder\pollb.html
copy source-file.html folder\pollc.html
copy source-file.html folder\polle.html
copy source-file.html folder\polld.html
copy source-file.html folder\polle.html
copy source-file.html folder\pollf.html
copy source-file.html folder\pollh.html
copy source-file.html folder\polli.html
copy source-file.html folder\pollj.html
copy source-file.html folder\pollk.html
copy source-file.html folder\polll.html
copy source-file.html folder\pollm.html
copy source-file.html folder\polln.html
copy source-file.html folder\pollo.html
copy source-file.html folder\pollp.html
copy source-file.html folder\pollq.html
copy source-file.html folder\pollr.html
copy source-file.html folder\polls.html
copy source-file.html folder\pollt.html
copy source-file.html folder\pollu.html
copy source-file.html folder\pollv.html
copy source-file.html folder\pollw.html
copy source-file.html folder\pollx.html
copy source-file.html folder\polly.html
copy source-file.html folder\pollz.html
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.
- [for /l](http://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html) - Conditionally perform a command for a range of numbers.
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.
- [variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) - Extract part of a variable (substring).

Comment: Why mess with FOR /L and substring? You could simply use `for %%C in (a b c ... etc ... x y z) do ...`, and then you don't need any delayed expansion.

Comment: @dbenham True, but I was using the OPs batch file as a starting point. There is always more than one way do something in batch, and this way the OP also learns about substrings ;)